# How to remove NULL results on concatenation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as full_name FROM auth_user
```

How would I do the equivalent of:

```
SELECT concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as full_name FROM auth_user 
    **WHERE full_name IS NOT NULL**
```

(which produces a `Unknown column 'full_name' in 'where clause'`)

Comment: So you only want to skip records where both `first_name` and `last_name` are `NULL` or either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways around this:

```
SELECT concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as full_name FROM auth_user 
WHERE first_name IS NOT NULL and last_name is not null
```

or,

```
select * from (
    SELECT concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as full_name FROM auth_user)
where full_name is not null
```

Comment: Would one of the above more ideal than the other?

Comment: That depends, whether if you have indexes on these columns or not. The query is pretty straight forward, but if you're planning to have group by or where clauses or other operations, the second one would be more prefferable from the aspect of readability and query logic especially if you want to operate only on full_name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT concat(IF(first_name IS NOT NULL, first_name, ''), ' ', IF(last_name IS NOT NULL, last_name, '')) as full_name FROM auth_user;
```

The difference between using IS NOT NULL in the where clause and using it in the IF clause is that you the where clause will eliminate (filter) the rows with null values, while the if clause will get all the rows but with a full_name that will not be "Unknown" it will just be missing the null components